# Remove all links that contain a blank href and replace them with text only in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying something like this:

```
$('a[href=""]').each(function(){
    var linkText = $(this).text();
    $(this).after(linkText);
    $(this).remove();
});
```

I don't know if my syntax if off?? Please help.

Comment: I have not used this much but I think you might be able to use it http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/ anyway, was there an error with this code you have now or what?

Comment: That appears to work just fine to me. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p8x5A/)

Comment: Make sure you have loaded elements first. Your code works fine : http://jsfiddle.net/AniHouse/NFmqh/

Comment: I gave it a try in this Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/yvYs9/) and your code works fine.

Comment: Did this work? I'm still available to help if you need it.

Answer (score 2):

`$('a[href=""]').contents().unwrap();​​` is by far the simplest way.

Edited for completeness, thanks @Huangism.

Comment: `$('a[href=""]')` perhaps http://jsfiddle.net/p8x5A/1/ you can still edit the answer and make it good

Comment: Thank you, that was a vast oversight on my part.

Comment: His question made me think how awesome it would be to have a plugin that removes all of the annoying links some sites put on mundane words (definitions and advertisements). Heck, I'm sure it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I tried like the following:-

```
<body onload="checkLink()">
    <a href="">hello</a>
    <a href="">test</a>
    <a href="www.google.com">google</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkLink(){
            var links = $('a[href=""]');

            $.each(links,function(index,item){

                $(item).after('<span>'+$(item).text()+'</span>');  

                $(item).remove();

            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

And it worked.